# DJI Mobile SDK on Android Studio doesn't work: FPVController: Couldn't load lib

Tags: android, sdk, dji-sdk

I'm frustrated with the Android Studio SDK
I'm developing on eclipse for a while, but from time to time, make the effort to migrate to Android Studio.
I can´t begin to work with Android Studio.

I´m trying to implement a [DJI](http://www.dji.com/) demo called "[PlaybackDemo](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK/Android-PlaybackDemo)" on Android Studio. I already make it work on Eclipse, but the Android Studio version don´t work.
The app start the DJIAoaActivity and then the DroneSelectionActivity as expected, but when you choose the type of drone, the PlaybackProtocolActivity don´t start and the app crash.
I don´t get the OnGetPermissionResult on the LogCat, expected from the PlaybackProtocolActivity.

I always get the following error:

```
11-11 11:52:56.338 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/CliptrayUtils: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()
11-11 11:52:58.058 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/FPVController: Couldn't load lib
11-11 11:52:58.058 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/art: No implementation found for int dji.midware.natives.FPVController.native_setIsNeedPacked(boolean) (tried Java_dji_midware_natives_FPVController_native_1setIsNeedPacked and Java_dji_midware_natives_FPVController_native_1setIsNeedPacked__Z)
11-11 11:52:58.186 28334-30034/com.example.myapp E/art: No implementation found for long dji.midware.natives.GroudStation.native_hashFromString(byte[]) (tried Java_dji_midware_natives_GroudStation_native_1hashFromString and Java_dji_midware_natives_GroudStation_native_1hashFromString___3B)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 28334
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int dji.midware.natives.FPVController.native_setIsNeedPacked(boolean) (tried Java_dji_midware_natives_FPVController_native_1setIsNeedPacked and Java_dji_midware_natives_FPVController_native_1setIsNeedPacked__Z)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at dji.midware.natives.FPVController.native_setIsNeedPacked(Native Method)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.api.DJIDrone.connectToInspire(Unknown Source)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at dji.sdk.api.DJIDrone.connectToDrone(Unknown Source)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.myapp.PlaybackProtocolActivity.onInitSDK(PlaybackProtocolActivity.java:473)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.myapp.PlaybackProtocolActivity.onCreate(PlaybackProtocolActivity.java:154)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
11-11 11:52:58.230 28334-28334/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Comment: It's not clear that people are going to be able to help without more information on exactly what you're trying to do. In general it's a good idea to try to have a minimal, complete and verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and while I'm not sure that's possible here, you should at least tell us about exactly what system you're using and what you have already tried in order to make this work. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @circular-ruin thanks for your comment. I post this without details, out of my frustration. I just update it.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly obvious from the logs. The line of interest:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int
>   dji.midware.natives.FPVController.native_setIsNeedPacked(boolean)
>   (tried Java_dji_midware_natives_FPVController_native_1setIsNeedPacked
>   and Java_dji_midware_natives_FPVController_native_1setIsNeedPacked__Z)

My guess: you've linked x86 native libraries, but not linked native libraries for the processor your phone uses. The curse of native libraries: you need to pre-compile them for every processor you intend to run on.

I'm not familiar with NDK development on Eclipse. If you were using Android Studio there would be separate build targets for each processor family, along with a additional one for building and including native libraries for all processor you've chosen to support into one single APK. Eclipse presumably has some equivalent concept to build targets somwhere.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, but doesnt help me, someone at DJI answer the following, but still cant get it work

The errors suggest that the SDK isn't correctly imported.

You need to use the New->Import Module in order to import the SDK.  Next you need to setup the dependencies of the app to use the imported module.

Finally, you need to add the following to your bulid.gradle so that the library files are found and included in the apk:

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['..\\DJI-SDK-LIB\\libs']
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

For me, I am an Android Studio guy, I meet a more serious problem. When I am trying to open the PlaybackDemo in Android Studio, and select the "Android" tab on the project navigator, nothing to show. It seems that the project structure is not correct and fit Android Studio.

Moreover, I check the PlaybackDemo just now, it's said that the demo is developed using DJI SDK 2.4? Which is pretty old than the current version 3.1.1. Seems buggy.

BTW, if you really want to try to the DJI Android SDK on Android Studio, I suggest you to check this Import [DJI SDK to Android Studio](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK/Android-ImportSDKToAndroidStudio) tutorial, it works for me。